# Grails 2.3.7 redirecting controller action with flash.message, i18n and html markup

Tags: html, grails, redirect, controller

I use Grails 2.3.7 and want to understand the following: I have a controller which sets a flash.message object with HTML markup from an i18n file (messages.properties) and args with no HTML markup.
When I call render, the corresponding GSP renders as expected, with HTML markup. When I call a redirect to another action, that does exactly the same (calling render), the rendered GSP shows the escaped HTML markup.
So what happens to the flash variable during a redirect? A simple println shows no difference. For reference, here is my code:

Controller:

```
class DebugController {

    def testFlashEncoding(){
        flash.message=message(code: "debug.flash.test", args: ["inner text with no markup"]) //debug.flash.test=<div style="border:1px solid red;">{0}</div>
        flash.each {
            println("flash in testFlashEncoding(): " + it)
        }
//        redirect(action: "index") //redirects to index(), html is rendered as text
        render view: "testFlashEncoding" //renders testFlashEncoding.gsp, html is interpreted
    }

    def index(){
        flash.each {
            println("flash in index(): " + it)
        }
        render view: "testFlashEncoding" //renders testFlashEncoding.gsp, html is rendered as text

    }
}
```

GSP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main">
    <title>DEBUG</title>
</head>

<body>
<g:if test="${flash.message}">
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
</g:if>
<g:if test="${flash.error}">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="status">${flash.error}</div>
</g:if>
</body>
</html>
```

So when I call the `testFlashEncoding()` action as shown above, the GSP is shown with a red border around the simple text. But when I use the redirect to the `index()` action instead, the GSP shows `<div style="border:1px solid red;">inner text with no markup</div>`.
The println statements show the expected values:

`flash in testFlashEncoding(): message=<div style="border:1px solid red;">inner text with no markup</div>`

`flash in index(): message=<div style="border:1px solid red;">inner text with no markup</div>`

So the content of flash is not touched, but somehow during the redirect Grails has some kind of switch that tells the rendering engine to escape the flash.message object.

For clarification, I use a freshly setup standard grails application, so my page codec ist set to `grails.views.default.codec = "html"` and I do know about the possibilities to alter the page codec or to force raw rendering, I just want to know what happens during the redirect (that scenario happens quite often in my current project).

Comment: Have your read https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Controllers/flash.html ?

Comment: Yes and according to the documentation the content of the flash variable is saved until the end of the next request, which is exactly what I want and expect. The content of the variable is not changed, but the behaviour of the rendering engine.

Answer (score 0):

Try either one of these:

```
${raw(flash.message)}

<%= flash.message  %>
```

Worked for me. It printed correct marked up HTML

Comment: As I wrote in my question, I know about the possibilities to force the encoding like you suggested, but that is not what I'm looking for, I'm looking for the reason why it works when calling render directly but does not work when calling a redirect.